# com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.2.100:80

Tags: android, android-volley

```
    String URL = "http://192.168.2.100:8080/DemoRest/webapi/aliens";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("Rest Response: ",response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Rest Response: ",error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Here i tried to get json data from my rest api.. where it is giving working properly on postman..
bu as i tried to link with android i am getting this error

Comment: is your mobile network is same as server network ?

Comment: `192.168.2.100` is local network IP. Your Android device has to be in the same local network to be able to access it

Comment: yes mobile network is connected with same wifi.. still not working @Soham

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058638/android-volley-noconnectionerror)

If your server is running from your localhost and you are testing on an emulator you have to use the right IP address as specified in this  [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking)

Comment: i am using android device with the same wifi connection.. but still i am facing the same error

Comment: using android device with same wifi connection.. still d=facing this error @I_of_t

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to command prompt, write `ipconfig`
2. Copy address of ipv4 and paste into your URL
3. Go to manifest and give permission to internet
4. In manifest inside application tag allow `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`